# Merge 2 ternary operator statements

Tags: java, python, ruby, ternary-operator

Let's say I have the following statements:

```
@string += @a == @b ? "X" : "Y"
@counter += @a == @b ? 1 : -1
```

Is it possible to merge the statements into one line?

(I've tagged the question with Ruby, but I am also interested in ternary operator in other languages. I want to learn some tricks for codegolf)

Comment: I'd suggest you also tag the question with other languages like python or perl, if you're interested in solutions for those languages.

Answer (score 3):

If you're golfing, you can use this:

```
counter+=a==b ?string<<?X&&1:string<<?Y&&-1
```

bit of an explanation, since it's a little hard to read:

```
string<<?X&&1
```

spread out this looks like

```
string << ?X && 1
```

where `?X` is the character [literal](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) notation:

> There is also a character literal notation to represent single character strings, which syntax is a question mark (?) followed by a single character or escape sequence that corresponds to a single codepoint in the script encoding

You could also just use a "normal" string here `string << 'X'`, but that's a character longer, and golf is all about short.

[`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) is just concatenating the string in place. You can't use `+=` there, because it's a lower precedence than `&&` so Ruby thinks it would be

```
string += (?X && 1)
```

which throws `TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String`.

So then, the rest of that line is just the boolean `&&` operator returning a `1`:

```
'some string' && 1 # => 1
```

so if you enter that part of the ternary, you concatenate the string and then 'return' `1` for the `counter +=`. The other half of the ternary is the same thing with the values for not equal.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have the following statements:

Nitpick: those aren't statements. They are expressions. In Ruby, everything is an expression, there are no statements.

> ```
> @string += @a == @b ? "X" : "Y"
> @counter += @a == @b ? 1 : -1
> ```
>
> Is it possible to merge the statements into one line?

Yes! In Ruby, it is *always* possible to write *everything* on one line, a newline is *never* necessary:

```
@string += @a == @b ? "X" : "Y"; @counter += @a == @b ? 1 : -1
```

There are essentially three cases:

## Newline for formatting

If a newline is used simply for formatting, it can just be deleted:

```
a + 
b

# same as:
a + b


def foo(a, b)
  a + b
end

# same as:
def foo(a, b) a + b end
```

## Newline as expression separator

If a newline is used as an expression separator, it can be replaced with a different expression separator, e.g. `;`:

```
foo()
bar()

# same as:
foo(); bar()


def bar
  'Hello'
end

# same as:
def bar; 'Hello' end
```

## Newline as expression separator in compound expressions

This is a special case of above. In compound expressions, in addition to the semicolon as expression separator, there are also keywords that can be used instead:

```
if foo
  bar
else
  baz
end

# same as:
if foo then bar else baz end
# or:
if foo; bar else baz end


case foo
when bar
  baz
when qux
  frob
end

# same as:
case foo when bar then baz when qux then frob end
# or:
case foo when bar; baz when qux; frob end


while foo
  bar
end

# same as:
while foo do bar end
# or:
while foo; bar end
```

And so on.

This is a special case:

```
def bar
  'Hello'
end

# same as:
def bar() 'Hello' end
# the parentheses are needed to Ruby knows where the parameter list ends
```